# While loop with a nested for loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Hello all I'm trying to create a while loop in a for loop.  The code will produce a bunch of SQL Drop index statements for me so I don't have to type anything except the table name.  The excel file will contain all of the information needed to complete the Drop Index statement. This will save me hours of typing.

**Expected Output:**
Run the code that works in a loop that will ask me for a new tablename then run the code and ask me for another table name or finished.

Here is the code that actually works with

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='UnusedIndexes.xlsx')
ws = wb['Indexes1']

ws.cell(row=2, column=2)
ws.cell(row=2, column=2).value
tablename = input("What Table Do you Want: ")

for i in range(1,200,1):
    if ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value == tablename:
        print("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE NAME = N'[", ws.cell(row = i, column = 2).value, "]')\nDROP INDEX [" + ws.cell(row = i, column = 2).value + "] ON "
                 + "[dbo].[" + tablename +  "]\nGO\n" )
```

Here is the code I'm working with trying to get the while loop to work.

```html
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='UnusedIndexes.xlsx')
ws = wb['Indexes1']

ws.cell(row=2, column=2)
ws.cell(row=2, column=2).value
tablename = input("What Table Do you Want: ")
finished = 'n'

while finished == 'n':
    for i in range(1,200,1):
        if ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value == tablename:
            print("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE NAME = N'[", ws.cell(row = i, column = 2).value, "]')\nDROP INDEX [" + ws.cell(row = i, column = 2).value + "] ON "
                     + "[dbo].[" + tablename +  "]\nGO\n" )
        else:
            finished = input("Would you like to enter a new tablename(y/n): ")
        if finished == 'y':
            break
```

***Excel File Format***

- Excel filename: UnusedIndexes.xlsx
- SheetName:  Indexes1
- Column A: Tablename
- Column B: IndexName

you can use any text(string) value in A and be.  Just need to keep the functionality of the Print statement in the For loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my own problem.  I had the while loop a little goofy.  here is the completed code if anyone is interested.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='UnusedIndexes.xlsx')
ws = wb['Indexes1']

ws.cell(row=2, column=2)
ws.cell(row=2, column=2).value
finished = 'y'

while finished != 'n':
    tablename = input("Enter a tablename for the indexes: ")
    print("This is the tablename: " + tablename)
    for i in range(1, 200, 1):
        if ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value == tablename:
            print("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE NAME = N'[", ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value, "]')\nDROP INDEX ["
                + ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value + "] ON " + "[dbo].[" + tablename + "]\nGO\n")
    finished = input("Would you like to do another table(y/n): ")
```